# How to move an array object to position 0

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am currently working with an array and I need to know how to move an object within that array to the first position, position [0].

I have this

```
<?php    
$extensions = array(
        '.com'      => array('whois.verisign-grs.com','No match for'),
        '.info'     => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),  
        '.net'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
        '.co.uk'    => array('whois.nic.uk','No match'),        
        '.nl'       => array('whois.domain-registry.nl','is free'),
    );
?>
```

Now, when the user chooses a domain from the dropdown, I want the selected TLD to be the first in this array.

For ex.

User chooses the .net domain, the array wil be:

```
$extensions = array(
        '.net'      => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
        '.com'      => array('whois.verisign-grs.com','No match for'),
        '.info'     => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),  
        '.co.uk'    => array('whois.nic.uk','No match'),        
        '.nl'       => array('whois.domain-registry.nl','is free'),
    );
```

Comment: is it important to keep your array in the same order after moving the entry to position 0?

Comment: Yes. Because the top TLDs are the most common ones

Comment: ok, so you may use array_unshift as already mentioned to prepend elements to the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the nested array into the larger array:

```
$ext = array(
    '.com'   => array('whois.verisign-grs.com','No match for'),
    '.info'  => array('whois.afilias.net','NOT FOUND'),  
    '.net'   => array('whois.crsnic.net','No match for'),
    '.co.uk' => array('whois.nic.uk','No match'),        
    '.nl'    => array('whois.domain-registry.nl','is free'),
);

$ext = array_merge( Array( ".net" => $ext[".net"] ), $ext );
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Mi2S9xTg

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because you have 2 of the same. The only thing that I want is to move a certain array object to position 0 without effecting the others

Comment: @GuidoVisser I see what you're saying; I've updated my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Remove it then add it again

```
$v = $extensions['.net'];
unset($extensions['.net']);
$extensions['.net'] = $v;
```